# How to add a transparent image to MS Access 2010 button control?

Tags: image, ms-access, button, png, transparent

Normal intuitive way, like hitting the Picture property's "..." button and clicking Explore to choose a file doesn't work with transparent ico files (MS Access returns an error), and it doesn't work on bmp files, as there is no easy way to specify transparent color for them. There are heaps of trials on the Internet to handle this with special software, extra modules or even custom multipart pictures drawn on the buttons - all way too complicated.

Is there a simple way to add a transparent picture to MS Access button control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Draw an image control on the form and select an image with transparency (I used .PNG files)
2. Change the property 'Picture type' to 'shared' (noting control name or image name)
3. Click the button control
4. Click the property 'Picture' and you will see the picture from the image control is now available for selection, select it.
5. You can now change the button control 'Picture type' to 'Embedded'

You should now have a transparent image that isn't compatible with buttons on a button control. For each new button image required, simply change the image control picture source to your desired image and then use that shared image as the image for your button control. Once you have your buttons with the desired images, simply delete the image control.

source: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7541

Comment: This is a useful workaround. I managed to do this in fewer steps, by clicking the "Add Image" button to add the PNG files directly to the shared image collection. Then I just selected it from the Image property of the button control.

Comment: I solved the error `There isn't enough free memory to update the display. Close unneeded programs and try again` by selecting the image after changing it to 'shared'

Answer (score 3):

In version 14.0.7128.5000 (32-bit) of Access 2010, no work-around is necessary. Simply set the button control's Picture property by browsing to your PNG with transparent background (you will have to set the open file dialog filter to show all file types to see the PNG files). Note that earlier versions of Access (2007 and earlier) don't support this or the work-around given above.

Comment: Did not work for me! Access ver. 14.0.7140 I got a message stating the PNG is not supported.

Comment: Didn't work for me either in Access 14.0.7149.5000: "...doesn't support the format of the file '...png'

Comment: If the database option "Picture Property Storage Format" is set to "Convert all picture data to bitmaps" is set (in Options -> Current Database) I find that you get the errors shown in the comments above. Changing that option to "Preserve source image format" allows me to set a buttons image to an PNG or ICO. I am using Access 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, when I tried the [1DMF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871275/2047725) in two versions of Access 2010 (14.0.7116 and 14.0.7149) the following error kept occurring when I set the Image control's `Picture Type` property to `Shared`...

```
There isn't enough free memory to update the display. Close unneeded programs and try again
```

...My laptop has 16 GB of RAM and according to Windows Task Manager there is 7 GB of physical memory free, so I don't believe that message is true.

Thus, I abandoned that approach and after much trial and error the following steps worked for me.

### A. Create transparent GIF image in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

1. Create image (or open image file or paste captured screenshot, etc.)
   in GIMP.
2. From “Image” menu, select “Flatten Image”.
3. From “Layer” menu, select “Transparency” submenu and select [Add
   Alpha Channel](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-alpha-add.html).
4. From the Toolbox, select the [Fuzzy Select Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-fuzzy-select.html) (the magic wand
   symbol) and use it to select the background of the image.
5. From the Toolbox, select the [Colour Picker Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-color-picker.html) and use it to
   select the background colour in the image. This colour then becomes
   the foreground colour in the Toolbox.
6. From the Toolbox, select the [Bucket Fill Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html) and in the Tool
   Options set its “Mode” to “Color erase” which erases pixels of the
   selected colour.
7. From the “File” menu, select “Export As…” and name the file with a
   “.gif” extension and click “Export”.

### B. Insert GIF into Microsoft Access 2010 Image Gallery (and associate with Command Button)

1. In Design View, select the Command Button control onto which the image is to be added.
2. In the “Form Design Tools” part of the ribbon, select the “Design”
   tab and the “Insert Image” button.

[image: "Design" tab of Access 2010 ribbon]

3. From the popup menu, select “Browse” and ensure that the file type is set to `All Files (*.*)`.
4. Navigate to the GIF file created previously, select it and click OK.
   This will add the image to the Image Gallery and assign it to the
   `Picture` property of the selected Command Button control.

Hey presto - your Command Button should now show an image which has a transparent background!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem is to just fake it by first adding your PNG image using the image object then place an invisible button on the top of it.